# Is there a reason a function won't accept a number higher than 4 in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, modularity

you know any reason why a function won't accept any number higher than 4?

This is all I'm doing. Works for 0-4, but once I hit 5 or higher, I get "A term is undefined and has no properties." But if I just put the number 5 in there, it all works just fine, so it's not an issue with the xml.. for some reason the function just won't accept anything higher than 4. weirding me out..... I can't see an explanation for it.

```
loadEpSynopsis(5);

function loadCharSynopsis(charNumber:Number):void
{
synopsisBox.titleText.text = bXml.characterlist.character[charNumber].charactername;
synopsisBox.descriptionText.text = bXml.characterlist.character[charNumber].characterdesc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of "bXml.characterlist" is probably only 5 characters long, so indexing higher than that is returning "null", which has no "charactername" property.

Comment: I put it in just a test file by itself and it works, but for some reason along with all my other code it gets unidentified... the problem must be somewhere else, but I don't understand why it would work for 0-4 and not anything higher

Comment: The sample code has "loadEpSynopsis(5)" but defines the function "loadCharSynopsis", so it's hard to tell without either the source to "loadEpSynopsis" or the XML data in question.

Comment: nvm... i'm an idiot.. I was calling a very similar function that was pulling from a different xml. so in a way his comment was actually correct.